500 Internal Server Error --> public_html/.htaccess: </Files> without matching <Files> section
Error log reveals this:
[Thu Jul 11 09:02:07.943146 2024] [core:alert] [pid 2141270:tid 22895643105024] [client 183.146.13.38:46683] /home/wwwstcchicago/public_html/.htaccess: </Files> without matching <Files> section
Contents of .htaccess file:
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

        # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

        # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
        # BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

        # NOTE: Due to a bug in mod_setenvif up to Apache 2.0.48
        # the above regex won't work. You can use the following
        # workaround to get the desired effect:
        BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

        # Don't compress images
        SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

Any ideas?
I am unsure of where to look within the .htaccess file for the (missing) matching  section.
Thanks for the help in advance!

Could it be that you have a stone old version of the apache http server that does not allow stacked IfModule elements in it's configuration files?

Anything is possible, but as far as I know, the stacked IfModule elements have been part of the config ever since I took over as webmaster late last year because the error appeared starting yesterday. There could have been an update on the server side, of course, but I only publish new content on a volunteer basis and only have access to the back end to report issues, but possess barely enough knowledge to be competent, if that.
